# How to add google font in transactional email template Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, fonts

I'm new to magento and i have little problem with fonts. Is there a way to use some google fonts in my transactional emails template?
I've tried to use google font using below way

```
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester');`
```

in my **email-inline.css** file, but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem by adding

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester');
```

in System->Transactional Emails->Edit Email Template->Template Styles,

after this, i am able to use my font and it shows in Preview Template.
[image]